# How to extract sentences that contains citation mark with R

Tags: r, regex, string

For example, I have String:

```
string = "The present paper describes an analysis of data from a cohort study of occupational stress in the Royal Navy (Bridger et al., 2010). Data from 2008 Phase III and 2010 Phase V of the survey were analysed to determine whether (cumulative) scores on the General Health Questionnaire (Goldberg and Williams, 1988) and the CFQ (Broadbent et al., 1982), were related to the occurrence of accidents over a three-year period (2007–2010)"
```

The result should be like this:

```
"The present paper describes an analysis of data from a cohort study of occupational stress in the Royal Navy (Bridger et al., 2010)."
```

please help me!

Comment: There are multiple sentence with citations i.e Goldberg and Williams, 1988 is in the second sentence. Do you not want them as well?

Comment: But the second sentence also contains `(... et al., XXXX)`. What do you mean by a *citation mark*? What have *you* tried?

Comment: This appears to be homework and the OP is also trying to subvert intellectual property rights (not that I like paywalled journals but the law is the law) and get the SO community to do that for them. Anyone coming to the should review the questions after it questions to see the progression.

Answer (score 1):

How about just using the powerful, underlying library that `stringr` wraps and use it to it's fullest potential vs rely on the crutch and regex hacks:

```
stringi::stri_split_boundaries(string, type="sentence")[[1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like the following where:
`.*` matches any character at least 0 times
`, \\d{4}\\)\\.` matches a comma followed by a space, exactly 4 digits, a parenthesis and a period e.g. `, 2010).`  If you think there is a possibility that the string might contain that sequence in another instance other than a citation, or is not at the start of the string, you may have to get more specific.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(string,".*, \\d{4}\\)\\.")
#[1] "The present paper describes an analysis of data from a cohort study of occupational stress in the Royal Navy (Bridger et al., 2010)."
```